# How pass/set environment variables into HHVM?

Tags: docker, hhvm

I'm trying to migrate a website from `php5-fpm` to `hhvm`.

We use Docker for local dev environments, and we set things like MySQL and Redis details using environment variables that are created using Docker's `--link`.

With `php5-fpm`, it was easy to pass these variables into PHP by setting them in `www.conf`.

With `hhvm` 3.5.0, I can't seem to find the equivalent. I got close when I found `EnvVariables` in an example config on [this page](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/runtime-options), but `hhvm` 3.5.0 now uses INI files for config and I can't seem to find where to set them using these.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out they were there all along in `$_ENV` instead of `$_SERVER`. Must be fastcgi_params.

Comment: What did you do to accomplish getting the ENV's into the fastcgi? You just set them as fastcgi_params and nothing to do with HHVM or Nginx?

Comment: @Perspective, you're correct.  Since you referenced Nginx, you just need to add a line to the server block in your nginx.conf file like `fastcgi_param <VAR_NAME> <VALUE>;`